# How to get list of packages used in a knitr .Rnw document?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

Using RStudio --> CompilePDF

In a .Rnw document to be processed with pdflatex, I'd like to get a list of all
user (me) packages loaded via library() or require() in the document.  I tried
to use sessionInfo(), as in

```
   \AtEndDocument{
   \medskip
   \textbf{Packages used}: \Sexpr{names(sessionInfo()$loadedOnly)}.
   }
```

however, what this prints is just the list of packages used by knitr itself,

> Packages used: digest, evaluate, formatR, highr, stringr, tools.

not those I explicitly referred to.  I believe this is because knitr runs the
code chunks within an internal environment, but I don't know how to access that.

I know about the file cache/__packages that is created with cache=TRUE; is there
any way to generate this automatically without caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is all the packages which are loaded except the base packages and knitr. If I then list all the packages and exclude those, you'll get what you want:

```
p <- setdiff(.packages(), 
        c("knitr", "stats", "graphics", "grDevices", "utils", "datasets", 
          "methods", "base"))
p
```

You'll have to make some exceptions say if you're making a knitr document about making things in knitr or if you want to explicitly load base packages.

Answer (score 10):

Without cache (`cache = FALSE`), what you want is basically

```
unique(c(.packages(), loadedNamespaces()))
```

With cache enabled, it is slightly more complicated, because the package names are cached as well; the second time you compile the document, these packages are not loaded unless you have invalidated the cache. In this case, as you have noticed, there is a file `cache/__packages`, and you can read the packages names there, so

```
unique(c(.packages(), loadedNamespaces(), readLines('cache/__packages')))
```

You may want to make the code more robust (e.g. check if `cache/__packages` exists first), and exclude certain packages from the list (e.g. `knitr` and its friends), as @sebastian-c pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that the \Sexpr{} within the \AtEndDocument{} block in the preamble is evaluated at
knit-time (the beginning of the .Rnw file, so it returns an empty list.  In the generated .tex file, this appears as

```
\AtEndDocument{
\medskip
\textbf{Packages used}: .
}
```

The only way this will work is to include the code to generate this text explicitly at the end of the .Rnw file
(which in my case is a child documenht, e.g.,

```
...
\bibliography{graphics,statistics}

Inside child document:
\textbf{Packages used}: \Sexpr{setdiff(.packages(), 
        c("knitr", "stats", "graphics", "grDevices", "utils", "datasets", 
          "methods", "base"))}.
```

Comment: You should not mix LaTeX programming with R programming. R/knitr does not know LaTeX syntax. If you want to avoid repeating this portion of document, you can just put it in a child document, so it can be reusable for all documents.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat different, perhaps more explicit and detailed approach, expanding on answers given previously. This would appear in the `\backmatter` of a book. The value `nColOut` is the number of columns of the printed table containing the list of packages used.

```
\cleardoublepage
\printindex

\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Packages}

<<packages, cache = FALSE, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, results = "asis">>=
nColOut = 7
packsAll <- unique(c(.packages(), loadedNamespaces(), readLines('cache/__packages')))
packsReduced <- setdiff(packsAll,
  c("knitr", "stats", "graphics", "grDevices", "utils", "datasets", "methods", "base"))
howManyPacks <- packsReduced %>%
  length()
numLines <-
  tibble(numPacks = howManyPacks + 0:(nColOut - 1),
    n = numPacks %% nColOut)
howManyToAdd <- numLines %>%
  filter(n == 0) %>%
  mutate(diff = numPacks - howManyPacks) %>%
  pull(diff)
packsReduced %>%
  sort() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  add_row(value = rep('', howManyToAdd)) %>%
  mutate(id = rep(1:(length(value) / nColOut), nColOut),
    col =  rep(letters[1 : nColOut], each = length(value) / nColOut)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  kable("latex", booktabs = TRUE, longtable = TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "repeat_header") %>%
  row_spec(0, align = "c")
@
```